# Multiple Multipliers for Lagrangian Relaxation

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I need a small help. I apply Lagrangian Relaxation method for my optimization problem. I know how to update the multiplier via -subgradient method-when only one constraint is relaxed. However, I could not find any clear explanation for the cases when multiple constraints are relaxed and multiple multipliers exist. In such cases, how can I update the multipliers based on subgradient method?

Thank you so much

Comment: There is a lot on that topic, see books by Bertsekas or Boyd.  Here are some notes I use for my class, see section III "Lagrange multipliers for multiple constraints" that gives some intuition behind the dual subgradient step in equation (50) and also (79):  http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/network-optimization-notes.pdf

Comment: Thank you @Michael, the document is quite comprehensive, I guess it will work,let me work a bit , thank you so much